# CSS - Style a DIV, when a combination of 2 CSS-Classes are assigned

Tags: css, jquery-ui, styles

I want to put Styles on a `div` in the moment when the `div` inherits 2 specific CSS classes.

The `div` allways has the CSS class `.bla` assigned, and inherits on click the jquery-ui class `.ui-state-active`. In this moment, when `.bla` and `.ui-state-active` are assigned, the `div` should get styled.

How can I accomplish this?

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">
            <div class="bla">
                Tab 1
            </div>
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">
            <div class="bla">
                Tab 2
            </div>
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">
            <div class="bla">
                Tab 3
            </div>
        </a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p><strong>Click this tab again to close the content pane.</strong></p>
        <p>Content 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p><strong>Click this tab again to close the content pane.</strong></p>
        <p>Content 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p><strong>Click this tab again to close the content pane.</strong></p>
        <p>Content 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

These are tabs from the jquery-ui tabs plugin. i want to style the upper Divs (with assigned class .bla), when a Tab is active.

Comment: Please post your markup and the relevant CSS, also the jQuery code that applies.

Answer (score 0):

Should work:

```
.bla.ui-state-active {
    /* your css code here */
}
```

You just need to concatenate the class names with a . (dot). So the rule just applies if all classes are present on that specific element.

Hope this helps :)